# Should a roller derby skater receive a penalty for removing their mouthguard on track between jams?

Tags: rules, equipment, officiating, skating, roller-derby

I've received conflicting advice from various Head Referees concerning whether I should give a skater an Equipment Violation penalty for removing their mouthguard in a valid Pre-Jam Position (see [WFTDA rules 3.2](http://wftda.com/rules/20140301/section/3.2)) whilst waiting for the jam to start.

This happens most commonly between jams, such as during an official timeout when skaters tend to relax.

[Rule 9.1.1](http://wftda.com/rules/20140301/section/9.1) deals with Protective Equipment, and states "while skating in a jam". This implies no penalty is to be given, however from a safety perspective that skater is at risk from an unintentional jam start, which is not an entirely rare occurrence at games I've attended.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Sports.SE. While asking questions always use specific sport's tag in the question. Looking on your question it seems a question about skating.

Comment: Skating is a general term, the specific sport is Roller Derby, a game played on quad roller skates (not inlines). There are also variations (banked track, flat track, etc). I flagged the question for review to ask for the relevant tags ('roller-derby', 'wftda') to be created on my behalf, as I lack the rep. Thanks

Comment: I have added it for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this question a couple of times.

The WFTDA rule is all about "skating in a jam" so skating between jams isn't covered.

However, a lot of venues have different insurance policies that will apply for skating between jams.

The head ref should be made aware of any policies and filter these through to other refs and captains.

I think it would be feasible to penalise a skater if they were violating venue insurance policies. But only if they had been told what they were to begin with. Maybe a warning then?